# Make all transactions gas-less for an EOA

Tags: gas, dapps, meta-transactions

As a service provider, I would like to pay for any transaction a user makes from my app. I've read about meta transactions and contracts that implement [EIP-3009](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-3009), which allow the delegation of gas payment to someone else (USDC v2 is EIP-3009 compliant). The problem is of course not all recipient contracts implement this.

[OpenGsn](https://opengsn.org/) offers the architecture to send a signed message to a 'Relayer' from the frontend and this 'Relayer' broadcasts the actual transaction to the network (and we pay this 'Relayer' via the 'Paymaster' contract), however in this case the recipient contract has to be written by me which must implement [EIP-2771](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2771).

I've tried making use of `call` and `delegatecall` to call methods of target contracts via my 2771 compliant contract but it's failing (for instance, the `transfer` method of an OpenZepplin ERC-20 contract called via `delegatecall` is failing).

What other approaches can I take to achieve my end goal - pay the gas for all transactions on behalf of my DApp's users.

Comment: Looks like a "smart contract wallet" is the only solution to my problem.